# Why i cant place is_on_floor here

Tags: godot, gdscript

Basicly this is my first time using godot and writing code int it and i dont have any past expirience so i wanna says sorry in advance if the problem sounds very stupid.My movment is almost compleated and i have one last probelem that was if there is any way to make the engine knows when i colide with the ground i searched up a bit and i found the is_on_floor method but when i tyed to use it it gave me this eror(18,41) misplaced and but evrything seems fine to me please help if you can and also here is the code if it will be useful to find the problem.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2(0,0)
const wspeed = 195
const GRAVITY = 30
var JUMPHIGHT =  -600
func _physics_process(idle):
   
   velocity.y = velocity.y + GRAVITY
   
   if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
       velocity.x = wspeed
   if Input.is_action_pressed("left"): 
       velocity.x = -wspeed
       
       velocity.y = velocity.y + GRAVITY
       
   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up"): and is_on_floor():
       velocity.y = JUMPHIGHT
   
   move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP)
```

Comment: This is a simple typo. You have `:` before `and is_on_floor()`, but it should be at the end of the conditional `if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up") and is_on_floor():`. I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. You have put : before and is_on_floor(). Also i want to change a little bit your code to be more efficient

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var velocity = Vector2(0,0)
const wspeed = 195
const GRAVITY = 30
var JUMPHIGHT =  -600
func _physics_process(_delta):
   
   
   if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
       velocity.x += wspeed
   if Input.is_action_pressed("left"): 
       velocity.x =-wspeed
       
   
       
   if Input.is_action_just_pressed("up") and is_on_floor():
       velocity.y = JUMPHIGHT
   
   velocity.y = velocity.y + GRAVITY

   
   move_and_slide(velocity,Vector2.UP)
```